# How can I query the object created by a specific user in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

when I `DROP USER regress_view_user1 ;` then error:

```
ERROR:  2BP01: role "regress_view_user1" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  privileges for schema public
LOCATION:  DropRole, user.c:1003
```

I forgot what kind of object I've created. i already drop a table (base_tbl) cascade.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-roles.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-user.html

**pg_user** only one oid type column, **pg_roles** also one oid type column.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-depend.html
**pg_depend**, there are 4 oid type columns.
So I executed 8 query (pg_depend with pg_user, pg_depend with pg_roles). but all 8 queries return 0 rows.

```
begin;
 SELECT * FROM pg_depend WHERE objid
        = (SELECT usesysid  FROM pg_user WHERE usename ='regress_view_user1');
 SELECT * FROM pg_depend WHERE classid
            = (SELECT usesysid  FROM pg_user WHERE usename ='regress_view_user1');
 SELECT * FROM pg_depend WHERE refclassid
                = (SELECT usesysid  FROM pg_user WHERE usename ='regress_view_user1');
 SELECT * FROM pg_depend WHERE refobjid
            = (SELECT usesysid  FROM pg_user WHERE usename ='regress_view_user1');
-----------------------------------------------
 SELECT * FROM pg_depend WHERE refobjid
            = (SELECT oid  FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname ='regress_view_user1');
 SELECT * FROM pg_depend WHERE classid
            = (SELECT oid  FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname ='regress_view_user1');
 SELECT * FROM pg_depend WHERE refclassid
        = (SELECT oid  FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname ='regress_view_user1');
 SELECT * FROM pg_depend WHERE objid
        = (SELECT oid  FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname ='regress_view_user1');
commit ;
```

Comment: The DETAIL tells you what  the "object" is.  But privileges do not show up in pg_depend which is why you don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

solved via:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON schema public FROM regress_view_user1 cascade ;
```